# Download a file from a URL and convert it to NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, url, nsstring

I need to get the contents from this URL

> http://google.fr/ok

in a NSString can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to worry about blocking the main thread, you can use:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
```

If being synchronous is an issue, you would have to either use a library like `AFNetworking`, or `RestKit` to connect to your server on the background thread and then notify you on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *err = nil;
NSString *urldata = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.fr/ok"] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:err]

if (!err){
    NSLog (@"DATA; %@", urldata);
}
```

Comment: @kratosphere: you should probably change/delete your comment at Richard's answer to hide the original URL.